# How to flatten Row object in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dictionary of a list like below.

```
{1016070000000: [Row(cola=53273831, colb=1197), Row(cola=15245438, colb=1198)], 10160700000201: [Row(cola=53273831, colb=1198)]}
```

I want to convert it into the below format without the Row object.

```
{1016070000000: [[53273831, 1197], [15245438, 1198]],10160700000201: [[53273831, 1198]]}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dict/list comprehension to parse the dictionary of lists:

```
import pyspark.sql.Row

df = {
    1016070000000: [Row(cola=53273831, colb=1197), Row(cola=15245438, colb=1198)], 
    10160700000201: [Row(cola=53273831, colb=1198)]
}

df2 = {k: [[row.cola, row.colb] for row in v] for k, v in df.items()}
```

```
>>> print(df2)
{1016070000000: [[53273831, 1197], [15245438, 1198]], 10160700000201: [[53273831, 1198]]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. Can you please tell me how can convert it to a dataframe like this ? ID             cola   colb
 1016070000000 53273831 1197
 1016070000000 15245438 1198
 10160700000201 53273831 1198

Comment: That's a totally different question There is not enough space to answer it in the comments. Please open another question